# Why does return value of fork() have 2 pid value in C?

Tags: c, process, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is it possible for fork() to return two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207656/how-is-it-possible-for-fork-to-return-two-values)

I'm new to C, and I'm confused about the return value structure of the `fork()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  pid_t childPid;
  childPid = fork();
  printf("%d\n",childPid);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is:

```
28501
0
```

Since `pid_`t is an `int` type, how does the `childPid` have 2 values?

Comment: Do basic search of what is fork before asking here. Its basic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're actually seeing the output of two copies of the executable.  When you call `fork()`, the process clones itself, giving two processes.  The parent gets the child process's PID as the return value, and the child gets 0 as a return value.

The trick is, the clones *share* STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR.  When the parent reaches the printf, it prints the value it had, as does the child, so you see both PIDs, with both processes sharing the same STDOUT -- there's no obvious way to tell them apart in your program.

Try rewriting it as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  pid_t childPid;
  childPid = fork();
  if(childPid != 0)
      printf("I'm the parent and my child PID is %d\n",childPid);
  else
      printf("\tI'm the child, so I received  %d\n",childPid);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and you'll see this more clearly.

For extra credit, look at the `wait()` syscall, and use it to make the parent terminate after the child.

Answer (score 6):

After a successful `fork`, you have two processes, parent (forker), and child. The newly created process, the child, gets a return value of `0`. This is the signal that it's the child.

So you're seeing the parent process printing the child's actual pid, and the child process printing `0`. This is working as expected, unless I'm missing something in your question?

Comment: thanks for correct my question. Sorry for this noob question, because the c has many low level stuff that I've never experienced before in scripting language